# Как указывается диапазон IP адресов

Tags: сеть, ip

Настраиваю fail2ban и не понимаю как указать диапазон IP адресов.

Хотелось бы прописать диапазон

от 91.79.0.1 до 91.79.255.255

Как это делается?

Comment: подозреваю, что указать подсеть, `91.79.0.0/16`